# How to add space at the beginning of the item or adjust left alignment for items

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate, enumitem

Hi I use enumerate to number items but second item starts before the first one. Because i add more than one number in item, I didnt figure out how to make a space at the begining of an item. Do you know anything that i can fix this?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$1)$] First item,
\item[$2-5)$] 2 through 5 items,
\item[$6)$] 6th item. 
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want `2 - 5)` to be left justified with others?

Comment: yes or at least it can be justified with paragraph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `abox` with a length is defined.

```
\def\abox#1{\leavevmode\hbox to 1cm{#1 \hfill}}         % left aligned
\def\abox#1{\leavevmode\hbox to 1cm{\hfill #1 \hfill}}  % center ligned
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

----- Left aligned

\def\abox#1{\leavevmode\hbox to 1cm{#1 \hfill}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[\abox{$1)$}] First item,
\item[\abox{$2-5)$}] 2 through 5 items,
\item[\abox{$6)$}] 6th item. 
\end{enumerate}


----- Center aligned


\def\abox#1{\leavevmode\hbox to 1cm{\hfill #1 \hfill}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[\abox{$1)$}] First item,
\item[\abox{$2-5)$}] 2 through 5 items,
\item[\abox{$6)$}] 6th item. 
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using the `enumitem` package the option `align=left` does the job:

[image]

### Notes:

- The border is from [the `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  and shows the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
    \item[1)] First item,
    \item[2--5)] 2 through 5 items,
    \item[6)] 6th item. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your value  makes the label begin in the left margin of the text (very slightly: ~ 2pt) as one may check with GSView or the latest versions of SumatraPDF. 2.28em would be a better value, but then the text of the items is not well aligned.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for pointing that out. I have revised the solution so that the text does not go into the page margins.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of the preceding solution that ensures both text of the items being aligned, and labels being left aligned on the ambient left margin (or at a \parindent distance if you wish), and a minimally computed label width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\parindent = 1em

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\begin{enumerate}[ $ 1) $,align=left, widest = $ 2--5) $,labelsep* = 0.5em, leftmargin = *]
    \item First item,
    \item[$2-5)$] \setcounter{enumi}{5} $ 2 $ through $ 5 $ items,
    \item 6th item.
\end{enumerate}

\textbf{With a label indent:}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\begin{enumerate}[ $ 1) $,align=left, widest = $ 2--5) $,labelindent = \parindent, labelsep* = 0.5em, leftmargin = *]
    \item First item,
    \item[$2-5)$] \setcounter{enumi}{5} $ 2 $ through $ 5 $ items,
    \item 6th item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]